# responsive + scroll effect at www.flipboard.com

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

does anyone know how the effect at the flipboard page is made?
i mean the responsive video and the menu which only appears if you scroll down. 
you can resize the browser as you want. only the top div appears and no menu or white footer. but start to scroll and there it is. thanks for ideas.

Comment: Why not view source of that website?

Comment: i did. but i do not get any ideas out of it. there must be some scripts behind it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

found out how to for those who like to know:

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
jQuery.event.add(window, "load", resizeFrame);
jQuery.event.add(window, "resize", resizeFrame);

function resizeFrame() 
{
    var h = $(window).height();
    var w = $(window).width();
    $("#home").css('height',h);
}
</script>
```

home is the id of the div which should be resized when the browser resizes. and 'height',h tells the browser the set the h of the var of the browser to the css height of the div.

Answer (score 1):

There is the upper div dimensions setted when window is resized and the image is in a wrapper div

Comment: We don't care if it is in JQuery or pure javascript... You can do it the way you want...